# Ajax.ActionLink alternative with mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC5 there is `@Ajax.ActionLink` that is useful to update just a partial view instead of reloading the whole View. Apparently in MVC6 is not supported anymore.

I have tried using `@Html.ActionLink` like the following but it doesn't update the form, it return just the partial view:

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "GetEnvironment", "Environments", new { id = Model.Id }, new
       {
           data_ajax = "true",
           data_ajax_method = "GET",
           data_ajax_mode = "replace",
           data_ajax_update = "environment-container",
           @class = "btn btn-danger"
       })
```

control:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEnvironment(int? id)
{

        var environments = await _context.Environments.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        return PartialView("_Environment",environments);
}
```

Partial view:

```
@model PowerPhysics.Models.Environments
this is a partial view
```

Then I tried using ViewComponents. When the page loads the component works correctly but I don't understand how to refresh just the component afterward (for example with a button):

View:

```
@Component.InvokeAsync("Environments", new { id = Model.Id }).Result
```

component:

```
public class EnvironmentsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public EnvironmentsViewComponent(PowerPhysics_DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int? id)
    {
        var environments = await _context.Environments.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        return View(environments);
    }
}
```

How can I update just a part of a view by using PartialViews in MVC6?

Comment: From javascript make an ajax call to your action which returns the partial view. In the success call back of ajax call, get the html from result and update your container.

Comment: Yes I could use Javascript, but I was wondering if there was a better way with MVC6 and HMTL5. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the code. Most importantly I would like to understand what is the best practice.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a tag as follows:

```
 <a data-ajax="true"
                       data-ajax-loading="#loading"
                       data-ajax-mode="replace"
                       data-ajax-update="#editBid"
                       href='@Url.Action("_EditBid", "Bids", new { bidId = Model.BidId, bidType = Model.BidTypeName })'
                       class="TopIcons">Link
                        </a>
```

Make sure you have in your _Layout.cshtml page the following script tag at the end of the body tag:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why data-ajax="true" block getting the files. Does anyone know that?
As soon as removed, the code works properly...

Answer (score 3):

ViewComponent's are not replacement of ajaxified links. It works more like `Html.Action` calls to include child actions to your pages (Ex : Loading a menu bar). This will be executed when razor executes the page for the view.

As of this writing, there is no official support for ajax action link alternative in aspnet core.

But the good thing is that, we can do the ajaxified stuff with very little jQuery/javascript code. You can do this with the existing Anchor tag helper

```
<a asp-action="GetEnvironment"  asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-controller="Environments" 
                                 data-target="environment-container" id="aUpdate">Update</a>
<div id="environment-container"></div>
```

In the javascript code, just listen to the link click and make the call and update the DOM.

```
$(function(){

   $("#aUpdate").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     var _this=$(this);
     $.get(_this.attr("href"),function(res){
         $('#'+_this.data("target")).html(res);
     });

   });

});
```

Since you are passing the parameter in querystring, you can use the jQuery `load` method as well.

```
$(function(){

   $("#aUpdate").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     $('#' + $(this).data("target")).load($(this).attr("href"));

   });

});
```

Comment: thanks, I tried but when I click the link, it enter in the js function, but it doesn't invoke the action in the controller.   $(this).data("target") contains: 
"#environment-container",  $(this).attr("href") contains: "/Environments/GetEnvironment/3"

Comment: Open up your browser console (network & console) and see whether there is any js errors or it is making the network call. You can see the response from your network call

Answer (score 1):

I add ajax options for Anchor TagHelper in ASP.NET MVC Core

you can see complete sample in github link :
https://github.com/NevitFeridi/AJAX-TagHelper-For-ASP.NET-Core-MVC

after using this new tagHelper you can use ajax option in anchor very easy as shown below:

```cs
     <a asp-action="create" asp-controller="sitemenu" asp-area="admin"
                        asp-ajax="true"
                        asp-ajax-method="get" 
                        asp-ajax-mode="replace"
                        asp-ajax-loading="ajaxloading"
                        asp-ajax-update="modalContent"
                        asp-ajax-onBegin="showModal()"
                        asp-ajax-onComplete=""
                        class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
                        <span class="icon text-white-50"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="text"> Add Menu </span>
  </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your project. I implemented it into my project and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use tag helpers instead and make sure to include _ViewImport  in your views folder.

Note: Make sure to use document.getElementsByName if there are several links pointing to different pages that will update your DIV.

Example - Razor Page

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        var myEl = document.getElementsByName('theName');
        $(myEl).click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var _this = $(this);
            $.get(_this.attr("href"), function (res) {
                $('#' + _this.data("target")).html(res);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Battle" data-target="divReplacable" name="theName" >Session</a>
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Peace" data-target="divReplacable" name="theName" >Session</a>


<div id="divReplacable">
    Some Default Content
</div>
```