# How to replace @Ajax.ActionLink in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Since MVC Core does not support @Ajax...how can I do the following in my razor page now?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("All","All",new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod="GET",UpdateTargetId="div1",InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace})
<div id ="div1">
</div>
```

Comment: Describe what you want to do?

Comment: I would refresh div1 contents with a partial view based on a button click..the question is what is the MVC Core replacement for @Ajax.ActionLink

Comment: Check out what is the generated html in mvc 5. The link should be decorated with some `data-ajax-` attributes, which you can apply in aspnet core.

Comment: Take a look at [Ajax.ActionLink alternative with mvc core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193604/ajax-actionlink-alternative-with-mvc-core)

Comment: Thanks Shyju! I found my answer in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't able to do without using `Jquery` or `Javascript`**, You can do something like this to achieve your needs.

If you are not using `Jquery`, Please [Download Latest Jquery](https://jquery.com/download/) to your Project.

```
<div id ="div1">
</div>
```

First add this click event in `Jquery`,

```
$("#div1").click(function) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/getData/",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#div1").empty();
                $("#div1").append(data.Html);
            },
            error: function (e) {

            }
       })
   }
```

Get the HTML:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getData(PartnerDetail partner)
{
    // Your Logical Stuff..
    string viewName = "_childDiv"; // Specify fully qualified path if different Folder.
    string htmlData = RenderPartialView(viewName, modelData);
    return Json(new
    {
        Html = htmlData,
        SomeExtraData = true
    });
}

public string RenderPartialView(string viewName, object Model)
{
    string htmlData = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    ViewData.Model = Model;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        htmlData = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
    return htmlData;
}
```

It will refresh your `div1` content with not refreshing the Page.